# Do we need to define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE if we are using read_json in different process

Tags: c++, boost

We are using read_json() in different processes and we are getting below crashes.

```
    #0  0x00007f062ce0d094 in std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*>::operator() (this=0x7f06120f4c90, __p=0x7f05f813faa0, __x=0x7f06120f4df0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_function.h:605
    #1  0x00007f062ce0c66e in std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*> >::operator() (this=0x7f06120f4c90, __x=@0x7f06001446e0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/backward/binders.h:154
    #2  0x00007f062ce0b87e in std::for_each<std::reverse_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >**, std::vector<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*, std::allocator<boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >*> > > >, std::binder2nd<std::mem_fun1_t<int, boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_helper_base<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > >, boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >*> > > (__first=..., __last=..., __f=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-spcdn-linux-gnu/4.5.2/../../../../include/c++/4.5.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4185
    #3  0x00007f062ce0aa88 in boost::spirit::classic::impl::grammar_destruct<boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> > > (self=0x7f06120f4df0) at /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/non_terminal/impl/grammar.ipp:324
    #4  0x00007f062ce09c5f in boost::spirit::classic::grammar<boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::spirit::classic::parser_context<boost::spirit::classic::nil_t> >::~grammar (this=0x7f06120f4df0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/spirit/home/classic/core/non_terminal/grammar.hpp:52
    #5  0x00007f062ce093f7 in boost::property_tree::json_parser::json_grammar<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >::~json_grammar (this=0x7f06120f4df0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:162
    #6  0x00007f062ce0987f in boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json_internal<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > > (stream=..., pt=..., filename="") at /usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/json_parser_read.hpp:310
    #7  0x00007f062ce08eb6 in boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, std::string, std::less<std::string> > > (stream=..., pt=...) at /usr/include/boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp:45
```

But when I define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE at every place where I used this function, every thing is working fine. But I didn't understand this because every process will be having different address space. So even Sprit annoyingly makes a static variable in grammar.ipp that'll be shared amongst all instances of Spirit, how it will be shared across different processes?

Comment: "Annoyingly"? Come on. No one forces you to use that library. If you can do better, by all means. Don't annoy yourself.

Comment: Also, consider upgrading to a recent version of boost.

Comment: Finally, can you reduce it to a SSCCE (also known [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). I'm quite willing to actually help you dispell the confusion and debunk some myths if they are at play. But, I'd have to be able to reproduce it first.

Comment: Project is at the final stage of completion and we got this blocker. I can't take the decision of switching to newer version of boost as I am just a developer here.

Comment: Well. You still have my invitation. It seems important to get this right, right. Best to not learn about undefined behaviour after release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So even Sprit annoyingly makes a static variable in grammar.ipp that'll be shared amongst all instances of Spirit, how it will be shared across different processes?

It isn't. Period.

Your program *might* share some files/named kernel objects on it's own, but the library doesn't.

This gives me worries though:

> But when I define BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE at every place where I used this function

You should define it **globally**. That is before inclusion of ANY boost header in ALL translation units.

Failure to do so at least fails to guarantee that all global state is guarded (think of locale character classification and properties) and might easily violate the One-Definition-Rule